# Fastlane always use "manual signing" when one of the target is set to "manual signing"

Tags: ios, fastlane

So we have multiple targets in our Xcode project and one of the target needs to disable the "Automatically manage signing". This works fine with Xcode and the other targets are also working as expected.

[image]

But on our old Fastlane script that works before has stopped working and I noticed the following:

```
[15:24:43]: Generated plist file with the following values:
[15:24:43]: ▸ -----------------------------------------
[15:24:43]: ▸ {
[15:24:43]: ▸   "method": "app-store",
[15:24:43]: ▸   "signingStyle": "manual",
[15:24:43]: ▸   "provisioningProfiles": {
[15:24:43]: ▸     "<bundle id of the manual target>": "<development provisioning profile>"
[15:24:43]: ▸   }
[15:24:43]: ▸ }
[15:24:43]: ▸ -----------------------------------------
```

For some reason Fastlane sets all targets to use `manual` as `signingStyle`. Also the provisioningProfile use is for development environment. By enabling back the `Automatically manage signing` for the culprit target the Fastlane scripts works again.

Any idea why is this happening? The Fastlane is 2.171.0.

**Update:**
Currently, I am force to enable `Automatically manage signing` for the culprit target while generating `ipa` files for other targets, then disable it when I have to generate `ipa` file for that target. It's tiring, but I can't find any solution to provide both `development` and `appstore` provision profile in the `gym` export_options.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late in time to solve your issue, which I hope is solved by now. I just experienced similar issue with my app and to manage this I finally understood the difference between automatic and manual. For instance, if you have multiple target you definitely need to be manual cause automatic will be solely link to the user profile (admin) in your app connect center vs manual where you will assign to your team and be able to work with different profile to provision whatever package you want to point it too.

ok the description is not the one from the doc, but in a nutshell this is what it does.

as for FastLane, as explain above, it is normal to be manual and you only want to point it manually to your provision profile like this:

`fastlane gym init`

your gym file should look something like this:

```
scheme("SchemeName") 
export_method("app-store")
export_options({
    provisioningProfiles: {
        "com.xyz.abc" => "name_of_your_provision"
        // You can add as many packages as your app contain and point them to whatever provisioning profile as needed.
    }
})
clean(true)



output_directory("./Build/ipa/") //that is entirely up to you
output_name("abc")
```

I hope this can help the next person in need!

ref:
[Fastlane GYM](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/build_ios_app/)
[Fastlane Xcode Setup](https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/xcode-project/)